# Dynamic Routing in Rails for landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I currently have this in my routes.rb

```
get 'admin', to: 'admin/appointments#index'
```

I want the route to be dynamic based on the user that logs in. But I can't do it like this, where should I set this?

```
get 'admin', to: @current_admin.landing_page
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the route to look like?  Like "admin/25" where 25 is the id, or "admin" and then the data on the page is that specific users data?

Comment: The dynamic part of that happens in the controller, if you want a route like `admin/landing_page`, you set that in the controller.

Comment: I want the route to be an existing page in the application, just which ever page that is will be able to be set for each individual user

Comment: Use a param then `admin/:landing_page`, and in the controller `params[:landing_page]`. Can be whatever you want, `admin/my_page` or whatever.

Comment: okay, how/where in the Admin controller do i set that param?

Comment: What are you using for user authentication?  Devise?  Did you write your own?  Can you post your controller code, just the index method will do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to introduce Controller logic into your routes. You probably want one admin_landing_page route, to which you supply current user as a parameter.

So in your Routes, you want something like this

```
get 'admin', to: landing_page/:admin_identifier
```

And in your controller

```
@current_admin = YourAdminModel.find(params:[:admin_identifer])
```

Then you can use @current_admin in your view to customize it based on data from the current_admin, such as

```
<h1>Welcome to the homepage of Admin <%= @current_admin.name %>!</h1>
```